# Not able to compile the main Java application

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting a number of errors when trying to compile my application.

This is my interface...

```
public interface userMessage {
    public enum DisplayMessageID {
        VALID, CMD_ERR, LOAD_ERR, 
        SAVE_ERR, DELETE_ERR, CONVERT_ERR, 
        FORMAT_ERR
    }

    String subuserMessage(DisplayMessageID DispMess);
}
```

This is one of my classes...

```
package terminal;

public  class UserCommunication implements userMessage {

    public DisplayMessageID DisplayMessageID;

    public UserCommunication (DisplayMessageID displaymessageid ) {
        this.DisplayMessageID  = displaymessageid ;
    }

    // a method for Displaying messages
    public String  subuserMessage(DisplayMessageID DispMess) {          
        switch (DispMess) {
            case CMD_ERR : 
                System.out.println("Terminal Sw Module cannot able to intrepret the input Command");
            break;

            case LOAD_ERR :    
                System.out.println("Controller reports there is problem in fetching the file:" + "\n" +
                    "1 Check if the source file exits in Database" + "\n" +
                    "2 Check if Source path is right" + "\n" +
                    "3 Check if you have access to Database");
            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("VALLIDD.");
            break;  

        }
    return "ddd";
    }
}
```

And this is my main program...

```
package terminal;

import terminal.userMessage.DisplayMessageID;

public class DisplayMessage() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserCommunication user_comm_to_terminal = new UserCommunication(DisplayMessageID.LOAD_ERR);
        System.out.println("Height of rectOne: ");
    }
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting when trying to compile...

1. at line,  `public class Displaymessage` : `---  Syntax error on token "class", @ expected`
2. at line, `public static void main(String[] args)`  :-

   ```
   Multiple markers at this line
   - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
   - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader
   - Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayAccess
   - Syntax error on token "]", invalid (
   - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete SingleMemberAnnotation
   ```
3. at last line , `} :- Syntax error on token "}", delete this token`

I am not able to figure out these errors. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you post the command line you use for compilation?

Comment: A word of advice - always fix the first error before you try to fix the others. It is quite common that an error early in your program will create many errors later on.

Comment: Thanks , i was using Eclipse IDE , get it solve by removing the  "()" is DisplayMessage

Answer (score 2):

```
public class  DisplayMessage() {
```

Get rid of the `()`.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should mark it as accepted (by clicking the check box right next to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` from the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DisplayMessage {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    UserCommunication user_comm_to_terminal = new UserCommunication(DisplayMessageID.LOAD_ERR);

     System.out.println("Height of rectOne: ");



}
```

}

should look like that. Hope this helps.